Error building android app using library mediapipe
I am writing an android app and using a library Mediapipe actually version. The assembly fails and an error occurs:
ERROR:
/home/kali/.cache/bazel/_bazel_kali/9fa70f8e5533edb3bff0ba9e130cf6a1/external/XNNPACK/BUILD.bazel:2223:19: Illegal ambiguous match on configurable attribute "linkopts" in @@XNNPACK//:XNNPACK:

@@XNNPACK//build_config:linux_k8

@@XNNPACK//build_config:android

Please help me find the reason and fix it.
I looked for a solution to the problem everywhere, but I couldn't find it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
